# Что входит в налоговую декларацию для Амазон

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon

Из стран СНГ Азербайджан. Хотелось бы уточнить, что нужно, для правильной регистрации аккаунта прoдавца. Конкретно что входит в налоговую декларацию.